# Parallax эффект неправильно работает

Tags: jquery, parallax

Есть небольшая функция, но она работает не совсем корректно.

```
$('[data-speed]').each(function () {
        var $bgobj = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));
            var coords = 'center ' + yPos + 'px';
            $bgobj.css({backgroundPosition: coords});
        });
    });
```

Она ставит одни и те же значения для всех элементов и получается, что паралакс неправильно работает.
Подскажите, как сделать, что бы для каждого блока подставлялись свой `backgroundPosition`, то есть отсчет начинался с нуля при попадании например третьего блока на экран.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте один раз повесить обработчик события scroll на window, а в обработчике находить все элементы с атрибутом data-speed и в цикле каждому задать background-position со сдвигом на нужный data-speed.